# Issues with Update Panels and Update Progress

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, vb.net, webforms

hope you are all safe.

I am hoping someone can provide some assistance in asp.net, webforms.

Background:
I was tasked with making changes (more user friendly ones) to our catalogue checkout screen. I have this working, and as some of this can take a while (to order that is) I used an update panel and update progress to show a please wait animated gif. This works great, however the design of the form has gone from one big form asking a load of questions to various steps, you know so I only show part of the form, for like what is your address, then user clicks continue, to be showed the next info we need and they click continue and again something else, they click continue and so forth until they reach payment. Now while I like having the update panel around the whole lot which is in a multiview, i have been told it is taking people a lot longer to go through as they are waiting for the please wait all the time. I tested this out without an update panel and progress and it is a lot quicker, so then we thought why not have it only on the thing that will take ages to run through which is the last button, confirm order button. So I went about doing this but quickly found out that this does not work inside a multiview, so I decided to destroy the multiview and just have visible divs. So depending on what step you are will show the div associated to it. So basically this is what I have

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
 some stuff here
 <asp:button id="button1" runat="server" text="continue" />
</div>
<div id="div2" runat="server">
 some stuff here
 <asp:button id="button2" runat="server" text="continue" />
</div>
<div id="div3" runat="server">
 some stuff here
 <asp:button id="button3" runat="server" text="continue" />
</div>
<div id="div4" runat="server">
 some stuff here
 <asp:button id="button4" runat="server" text="Confirm" />
</div>
```

It's in the code behind which I set which div to be displayed as there are other things in the form that need to be set but an example is

```
Select Case cint(whatsteparewein.value)
  Case 0
    div1.Style.Add("display", "block")
    div2.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div3.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div4.Style.Add("display", "none")
  Case 1
    div1.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div2.Style.Add("display", "block")
    div3.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div4.Style.Add("display", "none")
  Case 2
    div1.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div2.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div3.Style.Add("display", "block")
    div4.Style.Add("display", "none")
  Case 3
    div1.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div2.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div3.Style.Add("display", "none")
    div4.Style.Add("display", "block")
End Select
```

whatsteparewein is a hidden field so we know where to go next, either next div for previous depending on what user has selected.

Idea

My grand idea was if I could wrap button 4 in an update panel and show a progress indicator via JS. So I have the following.

```
<div id="div4" runat="server">
 some stuff here
 <asp:UpdatePanel id="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <contentTemplate>
     <asp:button id="button4" runat="server" text="Confirm" onClick="EventName" />
   </contentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button4" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
  <ProgressTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="imageWait" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="spinner.gif" Width="100" />
    Please Wait...
  </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Now here we can just associate the update panel with the update progress but this did not work either, I found everytime I switch to the next div for some reason the update progress would not work, I assume for the same reason it does not within a multiview. Anyway so I had a look around and came across using a modal pop up extender which uses JS, so I added the following

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalpopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateProgress1" PopupControlID="UpdateProgress1"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Then added the following JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    //Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    // Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Shows the modal popup - the update progress
        var popup = $find('<%= modalpopup.ClientID %>');
        if (popup != null) {
        popup.show();
        }
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Hide the modal popup - the update progress
        var popup = $find('<%= modalpopup.ClientID %>');
        if (popup != null) {
        popup.hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

So on a test area I got this to work and I thought as its JS and not relying on and update progress this would work as soon as button4 gets clicked. That again is not the case, part of me is thinking remove the update progress for a panel. However when I commented out the code that sets which div to display then it looks like the update panel works and as soon as I do a page postback it does not. I have even tried adding a

```
Sys.Application.add_load(setForm);
```

in my update panel and JS just to see if the update panel is loosing it's connection to JS. I am at a loss to what to do next, anyone else have any ideas and is there a way I can get only the button needed wrapped around the update panel as doing it on all the steps is excessive especially as there is a lot of JS scripts which need to get reconnected every time we move to the next step which is not needed.

Thanks for any help appreciated

Comment: Be careful with the UpdateProgress: it might be working. If you're only testing locally, requests might be so fast that the UpdateProgress flashes so fast that it can't be seen. Try adding a Thread.Sleep(xxx) for 1 or 2 seconds to actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

So I got around this by using pure js rather than an update progress. I created a div, styled it and use JS to open it when the button is clicked. As I am no longer needing the update progress I no longer need the update panel and when the page refreshes the loading div disappears as i first set it to display none.

Also in regards to speed I found out that the previous person who made this had loads of view state properties for things like storing data to just booleans. once I removed these and went down the session route for the data stored it was lightning fast.